# Accepted answer code causes a compile time error

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer

I got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25288373/2031560) to my question.

Even though it answers the question, it refers to the wrong class. I put a comment on the answer: should I edit it?

Comment: Yes, the posts on SO are collaboratively edited to improve quality. I edited it for you. If the author disagrees, they can rollback the edit.

Comment: That's how accepting an answer works. Unless you tried the answer provided and it works per your expectation, don't accept the answer. Even if you have accepted earlier (before trying the solution), revoke the acceptance and ask for clarification from answer owner by means of comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best thing to do is comment (as you have done) asking for clarification from the OP. As a sub-2000 reputation user, edits you make go through a [review queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), where others vote on whether to allow your edit.

Large edits that change the meaning of answers are encouraged on answers that are a community effort, but some people might be offended at your attempt to change their answer (even if it's an improvement, and most suggested edits that make a substantial change to a post are rejected in the queue, meaning that they aren't applied at all.

Until you receive [full editing privileges](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), you should comment unless it is a trivial fix (in which case you should  also try to fix any other issues with the post so that your edit is not rejected as "too minor").

Comment: I see you are utilizing your full edit privileges today `:P`

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Very happily, yes.

Comment: I corrected code in an answer once, only for it to be rejected. Since then, why should I waste my time correcting code when it could be deleted. So, instead I just leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

If the edited code works and it looks like he simply made a typo or something similarly trivial, I think you should edit then accept the answer.

Comment: You cannot suggest an edit for a typo, because you only change 1 or 2 characters. Leaving a comment is usually better. As OP you should be very careful when you edit, as you are the person that did not fully understand how the problem could be solved. What might seem a trivial typo to you might be there intentionally and you might just be infamiliar with the syntax or the meaning of said code. I have had an edit suggestion on my answer before where someone suggested removing a space 'because they assumed it was a typo'. It wasn't, and it makes me grumpy if someone butchers my answer.